# Using pandoc to convert from .tex to docx using XeLaTeX as engine

Tags: xetex, pandoc

I have been trying to convert a `.tex` file into `.docx`. Although the command

`pandoc file.tex --from=latex --to=docx --output=file.docx`

executes without errors, many parts of the text are not shown in the `.docx` file, because (I think) I use XeLaTeX to compile my `.tex` file.

Does someone have any tips on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Don't do complex things in LaTeX that Word is unable to do (or that Pandoc cannot figure how convert to Word format).  Common latex structures (sections, text with emphasis, lists, simple tables) have a Word equivalent and are well exported, but not any possible LateX code can be exported.

Comment: @Cybernetician - It's very unlikely that your issues are related to XeLaTeX. As Fran pointed out, the capabilities of pandoc are very limited. In principle only those things, that can be expressed in pandoc's markdown format can be converted. May be you have more luck with [text4ht](https://ctan.org/pkg/tex4ht).

Comment: it is difficult to say if it if possible to convert your document without a MWE. You can try to compile your document to the ODT format using `make4ht -ux -f odt filename.tex`.